# how to output all the xml in xls?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xslt, web-parts

I'm *trying to* develop a webpart for SharePoint, and it seems I need to learn **XSLT** to do it, modifying the `itemsStyle.xsl`and customizing a `contentquery.webpart`.

I'm adding a templates to my current `itemsStyle.xsl`, here's my current code :

I'm trying to make the output the whole XML files because I don't know how it is formatted (I dunno where SharePoint takes it)

So far, I can output the attribute name trough `name()`, but `text()` return nothing :

```
<xsl:template name="printP" match="Row[@Style='printP']" mode="itemstyle">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    Property:<xsl:value-of select="name()"/> |
    Value:<xsl:value-of select="text()"/><br/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Any other suggestion on how to figure out the XML format is welcome.

***edit**: removed useless part.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output the value of an attribute node, use `select="."`:

```
Value:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

`text()` selects any text nodes that are children of the current node. Only element nodes have text node children; attributes do not.

However, if what you're trying to do is copy the full input XML document to the output, unchanged, then throw all those templates away and use the identity transform:

```
<!-- Identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will copy everything through, unchanged (as XML, not text).

Comment: Ops! :)) Your answer is much more complete anyway.

Comment: @empo - sorry, beat you to it. :-) +1 for your correct answer though.

Comment: Thanks for the first part, it works perfectly. As for the Identity transform : I get only the node values as output :(

Comment: @Kraz: I'm not sure what you mean by "I get only the node values as output". You should be getting XML elements, attributes etc. as output, if you used *only* the identity template in your XSLT. Are you saying that you are only getting plain text as output?

Comment: Yep. Looked at the source too. Could it be SharePoint that is stripping them off?

Comment: @Kraz: anything is possible, theoretically. :-) I don't know much about SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

> **I can output the attribute name trough name(), but text() return nothing**

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
    Property:<xsl:value-of select="name()"/> |
    Value:<xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```